# 8:1 mux from minimum 2:1 and 4:1 mux

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

If 2:1 and 4:1 Mux are available in any industry. And If cost of 2:1 is 3Rs. and 4:1 is 5Rs. per unit.
Then how much minimum units and cost are required to construct a 8:1 Mux?
1) one 2:1 Mux
2) one 2:1 and one 4:1 
3) two 2:1 and one 4:1
4). Three units of 2:1

Comment: This looks like a homework question - what have you already tried?

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/102984)

Comment: As far as I can see, the answer to your question is none of the potential answers you've provided

Comment: This problem is about analyzing design costs. There are four different building blocks to consider - these are like an IC package that has independent functional gates but is purchased as a whole unit. For example case #3 each building block contains two 2:1 mux and one 4:1 mux. This alone isn't enough, you need *two* of these units to construct an 8:1 mux (one 2:1 and two 4:1). There will be two 2:1 mux left over, but they still add to the cost. Count the number of units and multiply by the cost per unit. Now do the same analysis for all four cases.

Comment: This is just blatant homework question, with no effort put forth and sloppy presentation

Answer (score 1):

There's 3 obvious ways I can see to build an 8:1 multiplexer from 4:1 and 2:1 multiplexers.

With this information you should be able to finish the other bits off by yourself. However, unless you understand how multiplexers actually work then you won't learn anything.

I recommend reading about multiplexers online.
[Combinational Logic - Multiplexers](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4eq35.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcrn2D.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMHgxc.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using 2 4x1 mux, and using the Enable pin.
That'll cost 10rs in total.

Imagine the enable pin as another switch line

[image: photo explaining the same]

Photo link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxCoB.jpg

Comment: You need to cost the inverter OR to have dual enables if opposite polarity - which some devices have specifically to allow such circuits.